# MySQL JDBC issues

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm currently working on a small project which involves writing information from a CSV file to a MySQL database.

I'm using netbeans and have added the MySql JDBC JAR file to the project which is needed for the connection. When running the code below the program does not move on past the driver manager.getConnection statement. I am lost for ideas at this stage. My username and password is definitely correct and I am certain I have the URL right. No errors are returned, the project seems to just get stuck.

I am using a database that is hosted by blacknight hosting services, would this make a difference?

```
 public static void writeToDatabase()
 {

 try { 
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://172.16.2.10:57983/db1320939_sa63898_main"; 
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"u1320939_kd","svpgalway21"); 


        conn.close(); 
        System.out.println("It worked!");
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        System.err.println("Got an exception! "); 
        System.err.println(e.getMessage()); 
    }
```

Comment: The IP address in the URL is a private address, so the database server and the computer running this code need to be on the same private network.  Is that the case?

Comment: It is most likely stuck while trying to connect to the db, and waiting     for `getConnection()` to return. It should terminate with an exception after a timeout.

Comment: why do you conn.close(); it causes your connection to close

Comment: Any exceptions/errrors?

Comment: I let it run there for awhile and I got a communications link failure error. When going through the debugger the program sticks on the getConnection line. The database server and the computer running the code are not on the same network no

Comment: @user3240957 you cannot reach a computer in a private network from outside that private network because addresses of a private network are by definition not valid outside that network.  Maybe the server has a public address as well, of is reachable via some port forwarding settings but if that's not the case, it won't work.

Comment: Ok the problem has changed slightly, Instead of the 1st error I am now getting Access denied for user 'Horan21'@'92.251.133.32' (using password: YES).

I changed my connection url to the external hostname.

I am using the username and password i would use to log into php myadmin

Answer (score 0):

Try catching `Throwable` instead of `Exception`. Maybe you're getting an `Error` while you connect to the DB and you wouldn't notice it. Also include a `finally` clause with a trace.